# Can I use the DuckDuckGo search engine without Creating a DuckDuckGo Email Protection account?

Tags: email, search

Will it be legal if I use the DuckDuckGo search engine  without Creating a DuckDuckGo Email Protection account?
Or
Can I use the DuckDuckGo search engine  without Creating a DuckDuckGo Email Protection account?
Thank you
[image]

Comment: Probably not the place to ask this but directly on SO, here is the place for Unix & Linux question which isn't the case.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is about using some website.

Comment: Not remotely relevant to Unix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://duckduckgo.com/ is a completely free of charge search engine. What's more, there is absolutely no obligation or reason to register. Just go to the web site and search without the need of registration or anything related.

Comment: Are you sure about it ?

Comment: @Md.SobrulIslam Yes, 100% sure. I use Duck Search every day without any registration. I did not even know there was a possibility to register. Just use it. Cheers.

Comment: And it's legal,right

Comment: @Md.SobrulIslam Yes, it is! https://duckduckgo.com/terms https://duckduckgo.com/acceptable-use

Comment: Thank you very much